# how to set nodejs v8 options to perform well?

Tags: node.js, v8

I learned that if I'm running NodeJs and other softwares(imagemagick...) on small memory machine

I can run `node --global_gc your_script.js`

and I'm not going to get OOME

---

I see many options when I run `node --v8-options`

but I can't find any document?

Is there any important options I should be aware of to scale my Nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag is called --gc-global or --gc_global, not --global_gc.

You may find this list of flags helpful: http://erikcorry.blogspot.dk/2012/11/memory-management-flags-in-v8.html